# Regular expression to match quasi import statement

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to devise a regular expression to test whether a line is a standard Python import statement where the "import" term is optional. E.g.,

```
[import] foo
[import] foo.bar
[import] foo.bar as baz
[import] foo, bar
```

But it should not match:

```
[from] foo import bar
```

So far I have these but they don't quite work:

```
^(import\s+)?.+(?!\s+import\s+).+$
^(import\s+)?.+?(?!\s+import\s+).+$
```

They do not exclude the `... import ...` style statements. E.g.,

```
>>> re.match(r'^(import\s+)?(.+)(?!\s+import\s+)(.+)$', 'foo import bar').groups()
(None, 'foo import ba', 'r')
>>> re.match(r'^(import\s+)?(.+?)(?!\s+import\s+)(.+)$', 'foo import bar').groups()
(None, 'f', 'oo import bar')
```

Can this be done with one regular expression?

NOTE: My goal is not to parse the import statement but to merely detect it. I plan on parsing it with the *ast* module.

Comment: The "import" term is optional? So, a line that just said `foo` would be considered an import?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes, just `foo` would be considered valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with the regular expression from [negative lookahead assertion not working in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13871833/369450), I was able to get a regular expression to match `[import] ...` and ignore `[from] ... import ...`:

```
^(import\s)?(?!.+\simport\s)
```